# Compiling simple Hello World program on OS X via command line

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I've got a simple hello world example that I'm trying to compile on OS X, named `hw.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I'd like to compile it using `gcc`, but I've had no success. I'd also like to hear the other options, like using Xcode ?

Comment: "No success" doesn't really help anyone diagnose your problem.

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Try

```
g++ hw.cpp
./a.out
```

`g++` is the C++ compiler frontend to GCC.
`gcc` is the C compiler frontend to GCC.

Yes, Xcode is definitely an option. It is a GUI IDE that is built on-top of GCC.

Though I prefer a slightly more verbose approach:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @math: `return 0` is implicit in main.

Comment: @mathepic: and the +1. It is not required in C++. If `main` reaches the end of the function without hitting a return then it implicitly returns 0.

Comment: Ahh, okay. I would still use it for clarity.

Comment: @mathepic: That's 1 opinion. Personally I find it clearer to not to use it.

Comment: If you're using a newer version of Xcode, you need to install the command line tools manually. In Xcode, go to Preferences > Downloads and install the "Command Line Tools" package.

Comment: Why `a.out`?  In windows I expect to see `a.exe`.  In *nix we don't need extensions.  Why use .out over no extension?  `a` is a weird default name too.

Comment: `a.out` stands for assembler output. g++ sets that name as default when you don't specify a name. I think most compiler default to that. If you want to read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out

Comment: Opinionated question: why do (or did) you prefer slightly more verbose approach?

Comment: @ThisClark Reading the OP his code is all squashed up. I think it is hard to read. Also; though I like the K & R style braces inside a function, for function braces I still prefer them to line up. I also like some blank spaces (as long as there are not to many) to make it easier to read. Also I don't use `using namespace std;` as it is bad practice. Which makes my usage of standard objects/types more verbose.

Comment: High school teacher here just getting back into C++ after a decade from college. My question was born out of the fact you excluded `using namespace std`, specifically that. Based on your reply I just did some reading on namespace pollution. Found [your article](https://lokiastari.com/blog/2013/11/18/so-you-want-to-learn-c-plus-plus-part-2/index.html) too.

Comment: Just a note, it's not actually gcc, at least by default. Write `g++ --help` and you'll see it's `clang LLVM compiler`. You can read about it on Wikipedia.

Comment: Also, xcode has nothing to do with gcc. I submitted post changes, hope I'll get approval.

Comment: @ÍhorMé This was an answer 9 years ago. At the time the compiler was GCC. Admittedly apple has since changed to using clang as the underlying compile but your suggested changes added nothing of substance to the question. Xcode has nothing to do with gcc or clang. Xcode is simply a GUI. underneath it uses the installed compiler `gcc` or `g++` depending on language. Whatever the `g??` points at underneath is irelavant it is the system installed compiler.

Comment: if both `gcc` and `g++` are both frontend to GCC, why can't we use only `gcc` instead?

Comment: @ecjb gcc will compile c++ code (assuming the file name is .cpp) but in the next phase linking, gcc does not automatically link the C++ standard libraries. There are a couple of others subtle differences. So yes you can use gcc but you need to add a bunch of extra flags to make it behave the same as g++ (thats a bit error prone).

Answer (score 45):

```
g++ hw.cpp -o hw
./hw
```

Comment: Out of all the other ones, this one worked out just fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Works for me on mac with the default g++ setup. I had to have the -o file parameter passed.

Answer (score 11):

```
user@host> g++ hw.cpp
user@host> ./a.out
```

Answer (score 6):

Compiling it with `gcc` requires you to pass a number of command line options. Compile it with `g++` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Also, you can use an IDE like CLion (JetBrains) or a text editor like Atom, with the gpp-compiler plugin, works like a charm (F5 to compile & execute).

Answer (score 2):

The new version of this should read like so:

```
xcrun g++ hw.cpp
./a.out
```

Comment: This gives me
`ld: can't link with a main executable file './a.out' for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Comment: @Rat-a-tat-a-tat sorry I don't remember, was 3 years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following for multiple .cpp files

```
g++ *.cpp
./a.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what the error you're seeing is.

Is the problem that `gcc` is giving you an error, or that you can't run `gcc` at all?

If it's the latter, the most likely explanation is that you didn't check "UNIX Development Support" when you installed the development tools, so the command-line executables aren't installed in your path.  Re-install the development tools, and make sure to click "customize" and check that box.