# C++ OSX Setup w/ Vs Code or?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I have to use c++ 11 for class and I was wondering how I go about setting that up on a MAC? I need to be sure it is specifically c++ 11 or I will fail.

I liked the themes in VS Code and would like to do it with this program, but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer would be to use [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), but personally I use [Atom](https://atom.io/) as my text editor and have several different compilers installed.

You will most likely need to install Xcode just for the build tools that come with it. You could install GCC or Clang via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or a package manager of your choice.(Yyou will need a working C++ compiler to install Gcc or clang via homebrew)

My suggested course of action would be to:

1. Install Xcode (From Mac App Store)
2. Install Homebrew(optional)
3. Install GCC and or Clang (optional)
4. Install a text editor like Atom or VSCode

The latest versions of GCC, Clang And Apples LLVM compiler will be able to compile C++11 and C++14.

If you choose to go with Atom, VSCode, etc... you will need to learn how to compile from the command line or use [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)(Which is what I usually do)

It sounds to me like you go to a school that uses MS Visual Studio and you are seeking a replacement? If so you may run into trouble down the line not having Visual Studio. If your courses are going to be using Visual Studio I might suggest Dual Booting your Mac with Windows and Installing Visual Studio on there.(Though you will need copies of each, but your school may provide. Mine did) That is how I got through most of my programming classes that depended on Visual Studio.

EDIT:
Additionally you will need to make sure that you have `make` installed on your system. Try running `make -v` from your terminal. If you get `command not found` you will need to install it, it comes with Xcode or you can install it via Homebrew.

Comment: Yeah we aren't provided with anything really. Visual Studio is not on the school computers or anything like that. I have an Apple laptop so wanted to get it working on it. We were just told to use C++ 11 only. He made such a big deal out of it and is very strict so I want to be sure I do this right. Is there a way to restrict the compiler to only c++ 11? I followed your instructions and installed GCC. Also, thanks for your help.

Comment: You will just need to set the compiler flags correctly. Odds are the version of gcc you are using probably defaults to C++11... but you can always tell it to use C++11 by passing the compiler the flag `--std=c++11`. If you dont know what that means you will need to read up on building c++ code from the command line and most likely make as well.

Comment: Do you have any recommendations for where to read up on that stuff? Thanks so much for all your help!

Comment: Google is your friend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073289/compiling-simple-hello-world-program-on-os-x-via-command-line http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~beechung/ref/gcc-intro.html http://matt.might.net/articles/intro-to-make/

Comment: Also check your textbook. If you don't have one I would recommend getting a book on C++ of some kind. There are lots to choose from but I'm sure a quick google search (or even a search on stackoverflow) will turn up a few good book names.

Comment: Rather than dual-booting, which risks making a big mess and making macOS unbootable. I would suggest installing VirtualBox and creating a virtual Windows machine that you install VS on. That way all the nasty Windows-y stuff is in a single file (the virtual disk) on your Mac that you can readily delete when you no longer want it. Also, your Windows junk can run at the same time as your lovely Mac programs rather than having to choose one OS or the other at boot time. You can also run Linux virtual machines alongside macOS, and Windows.

Comment: Another option may be to use Amazon EC2 and get a free base tier Windows machine and install VS on that. Then you can use Remote Desktop from school or home to get to your free Windows machine in the cloud without cluttering up your Mac with Windows-y junk.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I agree, I should clarify that I meant dual booting as a last resort.